# FreeImage library doesn't work on Visual Studio 2013 debugger?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging, freeimage

So, I'm working on a game engine in Visual Studio 2013 and I tried to use FreeImage v3.17 library, however, after trying to use the library on a simple example that is provided by the lib itself, the program is unable to load the image, unless I run it directly from the build directory. I've also tested an image of different formats, created by different software.

More specifically, using only the code below, stepping over the code, FreeImage seems to correctly guess the file type from the call to `FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename()` (i.e. `fif == FIF_PNG` etc.). Afterwards, the call to `FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif)` returns `true`, then tries to assign `dib`, but `FreeImage_Load()` always returns `NULL`.

See the comments with `// >`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const char* filename = "test.png";

    //image format
    FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT fif = FIF_UNKNOWN;
    //pointer to the image, once loaded
    FIBITMAP *dib(0);
    //pointer to the image data
    BYTE* bits(0);
    //image width and height
    unsigned int width(0), height(0);
    //OpenGL's image ID to map to
    GLuint gl_texID;

    //check the file signature and deduce its format
    fif = FreeImage_GetFileType(filename, 0);
    //if still unknown, try to guess the file format from the file extension
    if (fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
        fif = FreeImage_GetFIFFromFilename(filename); // >fif is assigned here correctly
    //if still unkown, return failure
    if (fif == FIF_UNKNOWN)
        return false;

    //check that the plugin has reading capabilities and load the file
    if (FreeImage_FIFSupportsReading(fif))
        dib = FreeImage_Load(fif, filename); // >call retruns NULL every time
    //if the image failed to load, return failure
    if (!dib)
        return false; // >Exits here due to failure

    //retrieve the image data
    bits = FreeImage_GetBits(dib);
    //get the image width and height
    width = FreeImage_GetWidth(dib);
    height = FreeImage_GetHeight(dib);
    //if this somehow one of these failed (they shouldn't), return failure
    if ((bits == 0) || (width == 0) || (height == 0))
        return false;

    // >Can't reach this from VS
    std::cout << width << ", " << height << std::endl;
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

This only happens when I run the program with VS's debugger, so my suspicion is that somehow the debug heap is at fault. I've tried  to set `_NO_DEBUG_HEAP` to 1 and try without debugging, but there is no difference in the program's behaviour. I've also tried to recompile the lib and link it both statically and dynamically, but still no difference.

So, my question is: Is there anything I can do to debug this further, *if* there's a solution?

Comment: Based on your code the image has to be in the current working directory of the application trying to open it. The initial working directory can be different depending on how you launch the application (eg. from debugger or explorer). You'll wanna check and make sure it's all correct.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I found the solution and posted an answer. I had the image in both the source dir and the build dir, but visual studio had a problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The problem was that, while using the debugger, Visual Studio was able to read the file type from the source folder *or* the build folder but *not both at the same time*. The solution was to have my files either in source dir(for the debugger) or in build dir, but *not* both.